# How can I create dates/times and compare them in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create a BBS using PHP and SQL, and I want to make it so the topic with the most current post is on top of the topic list. what is a easy way to check if one date and time is more current than another?

Answer (score 1):

From Sql using ORDER BY DESC

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY DateVal DESC
```

Other than that, please provide so table schema for us to work with, or what you have tried (in code) so we can have a look...

Answer (score 1):

if their datatype is datetime then a simple *greater than* ( `>` ) will do

But you do not have to compare between dates, just sort them according to date with descending direction ..

`ORDER BY [datefield] DESC`

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can use simple comparators (`<`, `>`, `=`, etc) for DATETIME fields:
`SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.date < 'datevalue'`

In PHP, I suggest that you convert your dates to [UNIX timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). After that conversion, you can use simple comparators to find out which date is newer.